# How to remove vuetify card automatically after a few seconds

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue card on which I am dsiplaying a success message. I have a functionality according to which, if the user clicks the `ok` button, the card disappears. Apart from that I also want it to disappear automatically after a few seconds even if the button is not clicked. How can I do that? Here is my component:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="show" class="notifications">
    <div class="globalSuccessWrapper">
      <v-layout>
        <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
          <v-card flat color="green">
            <v-card-title primary-title>
              <div>
                <h3 class="headline">Neu Benutzer angelegt</h3>
                <div>{{ card_text }}</div>
              </div>
            </v-card-title>
            <v-card-actions>
                <div class="close"><v-btn @click="removeMessage(0)">Ok</v-btn></div>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>


export default {
  data() {
    return {
      card_text: 'Success!',
      show: true,
      notificationsToDisplay: [],
      graphQLNotifications: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    removeMessage(seconds, timeout) {
      if (!timeout) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.show = false;
        }, seconds * 1000);
      } else {
        timeout(seconds);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
  .globalSuccessWrapper {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10000;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

I want to add this functionality in `removeMessage` in the `else` case under `timeout`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it from `removeMessage`, because you want it to happen without pressing the button.

You should `watch` for changes on the `data.show`. Details on how to do this [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property).

Inside the `watch` when the value is set to true you can set a timeout and **save** the identifier returned by `setTimeout`. The timeout should set `data.save` to false, this will close the notification. You also need to clear the timeout from inside `removeMessage` or from inside the `watch` method when the value becomes false.

You need to clear the timeout when the notification is closed to prevent the following behaviour:

- a notification is opened
- the user taps the close button
- another notification is opened, during the close timeout
- the timeout fires and the second notification is closed prematurely